# javascript hiding div not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have two divs and I want to show only one of the divs based on clicking a list element. I wrote the following code. Its not working. Its always showing me Div1 (or whichever one I make visible initially). How do I make it show me appropriate div? Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
    function showPane(paneId) {
        document.getElementById("Div1").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById("Div2").style.display="none";
        document.getElementById(paneId).style.display="block";
    }
    </script>   
</head>

<body onload="showPane('Div1');">
    <ul id="nav">   
        <li><a href="" onclick="showPane('Div1')">Div1</a></li>
        <li><a href="" onclick="showPane('Div2')">Div2</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="Div1">
        <h3>This is Div1</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="Div2">
        <h3>This is Div2</h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's jQuery way of doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltxkr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the list items are `<a>` which redirect you to the same page. than the body onload shows div1.

Add `href="javascript:;"` to the `<a>` to prevent this.

---

Or add the `event` arg to the function:

`<a href="" onclick="showPane(event,'Div1')">`

and in the function:

```
     function showPane(event,paneId) {
           event.preventDefault();
          //rest of code
}
```

To prevent the default behavior of the MouseClick Event. http://codepen.io/yardenst/pen/cKqIy

Answer (score 1):

Just another variation to the already answered

```
    <li><a href="javascript:showPane('Div1');" >Div1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:showPane('Div2');">Div2</a></li>
```

Comment: I always try to avoid this, because it makes the links uncrawlable by search engine bots.

Comment: but these links are used to make tabs! still not okay to be uncrawlable?

Comment: It's very common use to make the URL change for each tab (so you can save the page state) so I would use the link for its default use. In general, if your <a> doesn't need to link to other place, don't use <a> tag...

Answer (score 1):

You can add "return false" to the onclick to prevent it from following the link:

```
onclick="showPane('Div1'); return false;"
```

Comment: Eh, yes it is.. Right now his <a> redirect to the same page, which would always show Div1. If he would add return false, the onclick handler would actually work and there's nothing else wrong with his code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set # to href. Otherwise the page will get reload

```
<ul id="nav">   
        <li><a href="#" onclick="showPane('Div1')">Div1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="showPane('Div2')">Div2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should edit `href="javascript:;"`

Answer (score 0):

here is your problem:

```
<li><a href=""
```

make those to be

```
<li><a href="#"
```

when you do

```
href=""
```

that is actually a link to the current page you are on, which triggers the body onload and activates div1 right after the click event.

Answer (score 0):

It shows you div2 but then it quickly gets over-written by div1 again.(Try clicking the link for div2 very fast.) This is because when you click the link, the entire page re-loads and the onload event gets triggered and shows you Div1. To overcome this, use buttons or some other element which does not cause a page reload.

Comment: But you should probably use Jquery for this kind of thing. Its way better.